# How to match Model attribute with params from post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails so i'm not sure about the terms but here's the analogy.
I want to create a new record for Persons but the params from post are different from the model. Thanks in advance.

Persons Model:

```
:name, :email
```

Persons Controller:

```
def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:f_name, :person_email)
end
```

Comment: You'll have to either change the parameters you accept, or change the parameters you send.

Comment: Using different names in the model than in the form leads to all kinds of issues. You can add custom setters and getters and transform the input, but then you will still muss advanced features like validation messages that are linked to the correct form fields. IMO you would need a very good reason to fight against Ruby on Rails' naming conventions. Why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change the parameters you accept, or change the parameters you send.

The second is easiest: send the same parameters as your model. This will work with [form helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) and let you just feed the parameters into your model.

---

If you want to accept parameters which are different from your model, you'll need to transform them. There's many ways to do this. Doing it in person_params ensures consistency.

```
def PersonsController
  ...

  private def person_params
    # Require a person hash.
    pp = params.require(:person)

    # Transform them to match the model.
    # Don't overwrite if the model fields were sent.
    pp[:name] ||= pp[:f_name)
    pp[:email] ||= pp[:person_email]

    # Add the permit using model fields.
    # f_name and person_email will be filtered out.
    pp.permit(:name, :email)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you this partly solved my problem and it now saves but it returns null if the value is :f_name or :person_email.

Comment: @ZyT What returns null (nil)? And what's value is f_name or :person_email? Are your form names like person[f_name] or just f_name?

Answer (score 0):

Persons Controller:

```
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:name, :email)
end
```

Or change parameters you send.
Ex.

```
{
   'person': {
     'f_name': 'f_name',
     'person_email': 'person@emai.com'
   }
}
```